# How to move a directory out of ./virualenvs and into my project in PYTHONANYWHERE

Tags: django, bash, pythonanywhere

Just for the record - I feel so stupid asking this question.

I can not move a directory out of;
**home/username/django18/lib/python35/site-packages**
into my Django project here;
**home/username/my_project**

I did a;

```
pip install django-allauth
```

to install AllAuth for my project, which in turn dropped it in the above directory, not my project. To be neat and organised... I would like my AllAuth diretory to sit in the main directory of my project..

I have tried using the bash terminal, but can not get to that directory from it.

Comment: Have you tried mv home/username/django18/lib/python35/site-packages /home/username/my_project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not even try moving the installed package, because it (probably) won't work. Python virtualenvs [are not really relocatable](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/558).

Just create a new virtual environment in your project directory and install all pip packages there:

```
cd my_project
virtualenv .env
. .env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt    # if you have a list of pip requirements
pip install django-allauth
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think you are correct in this methodology :)

Comment: You're welcome. [You should consider upvoting and/or accepting helpful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: ;) sorry thought I had. Cheers